# django rest framework api key How to set view/endpoint permissions by apikey?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django "rest framework api key";
I have urls in my urls.py (I'll try to keep it simple):

```
a/
b/
c/
```

and I have created api keys; lets say "apikey1", "apikey2" and "apikey3".
I can grant permissions for urls "a" and "b" and then "c" wont be accesible by any apikey; but all the apikeys can access all registered urls (or views).

What I need is to restrict
"apikey1" to only "a/"
"apikey2" only to "c/"
and "apikey3" access to both.

I know I can do it with users by checking authenticated user in the request and then verify aganinst some list; if the user is in my list, keep going, else redirect 400 or whatever.

but how do I do that with apikeys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a table which maps the API keys with the URL path. Then, make a class RestrictedAPIView(APIView). In this class override the dispatch method to check if the API key and URL path combination are present in the database. Then in all restricted views, you can extend this class.

In models.py

```
class ViewAPIMapping(models.Model):
    api_key = models.charField(max_length=255)
    view_name = models.charField(max_length=255)
```

In urls.py

```
path("/abc/<str:api_key>/xyz/", ViewA.as_view(), name="A")
path("/def/<str:api_key>/uvw/", ViewB.as_view(), name="B")
```

You can add the view_name and api_key mapping from the admin page.

In utils.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class RestrictedAPIView(APIView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        api_key = self.kwags.get("api_key", None)
        if api_key == None:
            return #No api key found
        
        view_name = self.view_name
        
        
        if ViewAPIMapping.objects.filter(api_key = api_key, view_name = view_name).exists():
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return # API not allowed on url
```

In views.py

```
from utils import RestrictedAPIView

class ViewA(RestrictedAPIView):
    view_name = "A"
    
class ViewA(RestrictedAPIView):
    view_name = "B"
```

Comment: I will look in to apiview. I already made a table of my urls.
I just do not know what to link it with.
the requests to the api only sends the apikey, but I do not know how to match the apikey with anything. as far as I know, that api key is not stored anywhere for security reasons.

Comment: True, however API keys are not shown again on a few platforms for security reasons. However, the platform does have it stored in its database. Otherwise, there is no way to authenticate.

Comment: Check the edited answer, this will do.